# What does <!-- mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I saw that `<!--` and `-->` characters sometimes are used around javascript codes as the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
   function OnSubmitForm()
   {
        if(document.pressed == 'Insert')
        {
             document.myform.action ="insert.html";
        }
        else
        if(document.pressed == 'Update')
        {
            document.myform.action ="update.html";
        }
   }
   -->
</script>
```

I know that these characters mean comment starter(`<!--`) and ender(`-->`) in html. But in javascript?

Comment: the `-->` must be commented out too `// -->` to not give JS errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. It's an HTML comment opening stanza.

It has not been necessary to write scripts like that for a very long time. The idea was that it would prevent ugly things from happening in browsers that don't understand the `<script>` tag. In 2015, it's pretty safe to operate under the assumption that such browsers simply do not exist.

Same goes for `CDATA` open/close fragments (unless you're using XHTML, which itself could be the subject of another answer like this one).

Comment: I'd never spent time thinking about it but I guess this means that JavaScript parsers in browsers - or I suppose the HTML parser - needs to explicitly deal with that stuff. I guess it'd be the HTML parser which would detect that the node in the `<script>` tag is a comment, and pass its content that to the JavaScript interpreter instead of the implicit CDATA text node content. I don't work on browser innards however so that's just a guess.

Comment: actually I think JavaScript engines just have special logic to ignore `<!--` in the code. Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/t1wrwqtc/ (that's in the script part, so shouldn't be going through the HTML parser at all). Anyway, the 100% safe way to avoid such issues is to always use non-embedded JavaScript.

Comment: @Dave wow that's ... astonishing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`<!--` and `-->` are html comments. They are usually found in older style script tags because ancient browsers would sometimes render the content between script tags (This prevented this from happening).

You're safe to not include them if you wish.